# What is wrong with my cropping logic?

Tags: c#, graphics

I am trying to crop a portrait image into a specific landscape size by cropping from the middle, and I seem to be doing things wrong.  Right now I have the following code:

```
// Check the orientation
if(original.Height > original.Width) {
    var bmp = new Bitmap(original);
    int cropHeightOffset = (desiredHeight - original.Height) / 2;
    var totalArea = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0),
                                  new Size(original.Width, original.Height));
    var cropArea = new Rectangle(new Point(0, cropHeightOffset),
                                 new Size(desiredWidth, desiredHeight));

    // Create new blank image of the desired size
    var newBmp = new Bitmap(bmp, new Size(desiredWidth, desiredHeight));

    // Crop image
    var cropper = Graphics.FromImage(newBmp);

    // Draw it
    cropper.DrawImage(bmp, totalArea, cropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    // Save
    original.Dispose();
    newBmp.Save(imagePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

When this happens it essentially resizes the image (thus distorting it) instead of cropping it.

If I switch around the `totalArea` and `cropArea` in my `cropper.DrawImage` call then it crops from the bottom, but it loops the image around twice (but is still the correct size).

I'm utterly confused on how to do this properly.

---

**Edit:** Here are some examples of things I have tried.  There's something I'm not getting, I'm just not sure what.

Using Oliver's code:

```
            var targetArea = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(desiredWidth, desiredHeight));
            var cropArea = new Rectangle(new Point(0, cropHeightOffset), new Size(desiredWidth, desiredHeight));

            ...

            // Draw it
            cropper.DrawImage(bmp, targetArea, cropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

gives me http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6753359/crop/7278482-2.jpeg

```
            var targetArea = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(desiredWidth, desiredHeight));
            var cropArea = new Rectangle(new Point(0, cropHeightOffset), new Size(original.Width, original.Height));
            ......

            // Draw it
            cropper.DrawImage(bmp, cropArea, targetArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

gives me http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6753359/crop/7278482-1.jpeg

The original image is: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6753359/crop/7278482%20orig.jpeg

Comment: I may be wrong, but from the MSDN documentation, I think the second argument for `DrawImage` should be the area on the *destination* bitmap, so it should have the height and width of the crop area.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm telling it in the code posted above?

Comment: No; you're giving it the original area as the second argument and the target area as the third.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the target area, not the total area:

```
var newSize = new Size(desiredWidth, desiredHeight);
var targetArea = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), newSize);
var cropArea = new Rectangle(new Point(0, cropHeightOffset), newSize);  
...
cropper.DrawImage(bmp, targetArea, cropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Comment: That only worked when I had the croparea with 0,0 offset.  When I add in `cropHeightOffset` the image loops around.  Using cropHeighOffset in both areas didn't work either, that just caused the image to resize

Comment: I updated the question with examples of what I get with your code

Comment: Nevermind, this works.  I fail at subtraction, and my offset was calculated backwards (should have been original - desired)